# Devtools failed to load source map unexpected token warning

Tags: html, angular, dev-tools

En consola, me aparecen varios warnings estoy buscando la manera de corregirlos ya que antes no aparecían, y no quiero ocultarlos dando en las configuraciones del navegador, sino que quiero corregirlo de raíz, alguna idea para solucionar esto, estoy en angular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre el error, fue bastante curioso por defecto angular tiene activada la opcion de sourceMap en true, y en este caso en diferentes ambientes estaba en false, por lo cual me aparecen estos maps en consola, no afectan pero estan ahí, estuve buscando y me base de este par de respuestas para solucionarlo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879588/what-will-happen-if-sourcemap-is-set-as-false-in-angular

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862170/angular-6-devtools-failed-to-parse-sourcemap-https-example-com-ngsw-worker